# Rank Macro linked to a Button returns error 400

Tags: excel, vba, button, rank

in my main macro I have created a button:

```
Dim btn As Button
Set btn = WS1.Buttons.Add(Range("h2").Left, Range("h2").Top, Range("h2").Width, Range("h2").Height)
With btn
  .OnAction = "File_01.Order_Ranking"
  .Caption = "Order Ranking"
  .Name = "Order_Ranking"
End With
```

and then I have created the Order_Ranking macro linked to the button:

```
Sub Order_Ranking()
    Range("B2:E18").Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), _
                     Order1:=xlAscending, _
                     Header:=xlYes    
End Sub
```

When I press on the button I get error 400 with no description.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Works for me if I change `.OnAction = "File_01.Order_Ranking"` to `.OnAction = "Order_Ranking"`.  Does the main code check if the button is already created?  Each time you run that code it will create another button on top of the old one - you won't see them as they're perfectly placed on top of each other.

Comment: If I remove "File_01" I get the error "Cannot run the macro: The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled". If I comment the rank code lines in the order_ranking macro and I insert a print value operation it works fine.

Comment: Isn't this the same problem with the sort as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452626) ? Qualify the range  `Range("B2:E18")` with the sheet.

Comment: Exactly, btw I have just solved using `Worksheets("COPPIE + RANKING").Range("D2").Sort Key1:=Worksheets("COPPIE + RANKING").Range("D2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but at the end this formula worked:

```
Worksheets("COPPIE + RANKING").Range("D2").Sort Key1:=Worksheets("COPPIE + RANKING").Range("D2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?